# React get element from child after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Please help me with the following issue,
I'm using react 15.4.0, react-bootstrap 0.32.1,

I need to display a datepicker (Bootstrap) from a modal (which is a component triggered by a button).

I've tried with refs on the input with no avail (this.refs on componentDidMount() is empty {});

Since this is a child component the componentDidMount() gets called before the parent's (not on demand so when i try to click my input the element does not exist on the DOM)

Caller:

```
<ModalRequestChange key={'request-change' + row.id} id={row.id}  props={this.props} />
```

Modal component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        var date_input = $('input[name="date"]');
        var options = {
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            showMeridian: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true,
            startDate: new Date(),
            minuteStep: 4,
            position: "bottom left",
            origin: "top left",
            orientation: "right",
        };
        date_input.datepicker(options).on('changeDate', (e) => {
            this.handleChange(e);
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isLoading ? <Loader/>: ''}
                <Modal backdrop={'static'} attentionClass={''} show={this.props.show} onHide={this.close} backdrop='static' keyboard={false} attentionClass={''}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Edit Request Campaign</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <div>Please use this form to modify your request.</div>
                        <form ref="form">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <input className="form-control" id="date" type="text" ref="date" name="date" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.fields.date} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} required/>
                                        <label className="form-control-placeholder" htmlFor="date">When do you need this HTML by? mm/dd/yy *</label>
                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback icon-calendar"><i className="icon-th"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution if you got the same problem, I was wrapping my Modal (react-bootstrap modal) on another component so I needed to pass the function 'onEntered' to the component component's.

Caller:

```
  setDatePicker() {
        var options = {
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            showMeridian: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            todayBtn: true,
            startDate: new Date(),
            minuteStep: 4,
            position: "bottom left",
            origin: "top left",
            orientation: "right",
        };

        $('input[name="date"]').datepicker(options).on('changeDate', (e) => {
            this.handleChange(e);
        });
    }

<ModalRequestChange key={'request-change' + row.id} id={row.id}  props={this.props} onEntered={this.setDatePicker()}/>
```

Modal:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isLoading ? <Loader/>: ''}
                <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.close} backdrop='static' keyboard={false} attentionClass={''} onEntered={this.props.onEntered.bind(this)}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Edit Request Campaign</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <div>Please use this form to modify your request.</div>
                        <form ref="form">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <input className="form-control" id="date" type="text" ref="date" name="date" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.fields.date} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} required/>
                                        <label className="form-control-placeholder" htmlFor="date">When do you need this HTML by? mm/dd/yy *</label>
                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback icon-calendar"><i className="icon-th"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

This way you can get the fully rendered on DOM modal and operate on it.